# Account for prevalence in sample size calculations?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sample-size, non-inferiority

I want to calculate the sample size for a retrospective non-inferiority study. I want to test if methodB has a sensitivity that is non-inferior to methodA in regards to detecting head traumas on patients.
MethodA has a sensitivity of 80%, and the non-inferior margin is 5%.

I'm using a sample size command in Stata:

```
ssi 0.80 0.05, a(0.05) power(0.8) non
```

For information/for those that aren't familiar with Stata or the ssi-command: The result is the same as when using the online SealedEnvelope calculator: https://www.sealedenvelope.com/power/binary-noninferior/

The result is 792 per group. Since this is a matched, retrospective design, MethodA and MethodB are both used on all patients, thus I only need one group.

My question is: do I need to include 792 patients in total? Or do I need to include 792 head traumas?

- The prevalence for head traumas is approx. 10%, so that would mean 792/0.1 = 7920 patients.

Thank you for your time in advance!